# calling custom price.phtml from admin

Tags: product, price

I found product price comes from catalog/product/price.phtml

is there any way in admin > catalog > category > custom deign

to call my custom price.html for specifi category

something like below

```
<reference name="product.price">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view_mour.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: can you please let me know what you have try

Comment: see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for…

```
<layout>
    <default>
         <reference name="catalog_product_price_template">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>simple</type><block>catalog/product_price</block><template>killerprice/price.phtml</template></action>
            <!-- duplicate for each product type you need to handle i.e. change the value of the <type> node" -->
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Have a look in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` to see why this works

Comment: not works ..../

Comment: @user1799722 try to debug why it not works, or give some more information about the issue. This is impossible to reproduce